# Accessing Data Controls from a different form

Tags: c#, winforms

i have two forms, form A and form B, to access form B from from A i pass form B in the constructor of form A, that way i am able to access a gridview.

Suggestions were made directing me towards exposing my gridview in a public property and passing it to the other form i want to access it from.

This is my understanding of what was suggested to me:

```
public RadGridView Grid
{
    get { return GridViewDisplay; }
}
```

then i pass this property to my second form:

```
Form1 f1 = new form1();
Form2 f2 = new form2(f1.Grid);
```

This is my issue here:

```
public void DockAllWindows()
    {
        SideBar sb = new SideBar();
        Summary sm = new Summary();
        SalesPoint sp = new SalesPoint(sb, sm); // This is where my issue is, Point A
        StartPage start = new StartPage();
        radDock.DockControl(sp, (DockPosition.Fill), DockType.Document);
        radDock.DockControl(start, (DockPosition.Fill), DockType.Document);
        radDock.DockControl(sm, (DockPosition.Right), DockType.ToolWindow);
    }
```

At Point A i am passing an object instance of my summary form to my SalePoint form.
therefore i cannot execute the following code as it would generate an error:

```
Summary sm = new Summary(sp.Grid); // Error right here
            SalesPoint sp = new SalesPoint(sb, sm);
```

I would like some help getting around the above error.

Comment: Look at your Summary class.  What object can you pass in the constructor?  We can't see it from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Summary.Grid property after you've created your SalesPoint class.

```
Summary sm = new Summary();
SalesPoint sp = new SalesPoint(sb, sm);
sm.Grid = sp.Grid.
```

To be clear you need a public grid property on your SalesPoint class and one on your Summary class. And make you implement the set on the property of the Summary class so you know when someone else changes it.

```
public RadGridView Grid
{
    get { return grid; }
    set
    {
        if (grid != value)
        {
            grid = value;
            // Add any special processing that summary needs to do to pull data from the SalesPoint Grid property.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i dunno why i was voted down for this but you obviously understood my problem, it looks promising, i will try it out to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you it worked just the way i wanted it to, you were very helpful, thanks a lot. :)